# CakePHP 3 Rest Api JWT plugin Form login Not working

Tags: rest, cakephp-3.0

I am using ADmad/cakephp-jwt-auth plugin for Json web token authentication for rest api.

For the token generation we i am sending email and password to login via form . but it fails i don't what is issue.

Here is the my settings. in AppController.php

```
$this->loadComponent('Auth', [
            'Form' => [
                            'fields' => [
                                    'username' => 'email',
                                    'password' => 'password'
                            ]
             ],
            'authenticate' => [
                    'ADmad/JwtAuth.Jwt' => [
                            'parameter' => '_token',
                            'userModel' => 'Users',
                            'scope' => ['Users.active' => 1],
                            'fields' => [
                                    'id' => 'id'
                            ]
                    ]
            ],
            'unauthorizedRedirect' => false,
            // Config below is available since CakePHP 3.1.
            // It makes user info available in controller's beforeFilter() which is not possible in CakePHP 3.0.
            'checkAuthIn' => 'Controller.initialize',
    ]);
```

UsersController Token generation method script;

```
public function token(){
    $user = $this->Auth->identify();
    if (!$user) {
        throw new UnauthorizedException('Invalid email or password');
    }

        $this->set([
            'success' => true,
            'data' => [
                'token' => $token = \JWT::encode([
                    'id' => $user['id'],
                    'exp' =>  time() + 604800
                ],
                Security::salt())
            ],
            '_serialize' => ['success', 'data']
        ]);
}
```

The json data i am posting is

```
{
 'email' : 'muni@smart.com',
'password': '123'
}
```

Please say me what is mistake?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Form must be in the authenticate**

```
 $this->loadComponent('Auth', [
                'authenticate' => [
                    'Form' => [
                        'fields' => [
                            'username' => 'email',
                            'password' => 'password'
                        ]
                    ],
                    'ADmad/JwtAuth.Jwt' => [
                        'parameter' => '_token',
                        'userModel' => 'Users',
                        'fields' => [
                              'id' => 'id'
                        ]
                ]
            ]
        ]);
```